# Linking error while ICE project compilation

Tags: compilation, linker, ice

While compiling my project on Ubuntu 14.04 I got the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccpU0kVX.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN7IceUtil19NullHandleExceptionC1EPKci'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIceUtil.so.36: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

While compiling ICE project with a command:

`g++ -I. server.cpp -lIce -lpthread`

This is propably some problem with linking but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

With Ice 3.6, you need to link with Ice and IceUtil:

```
g++ -o server server.cpp -pthread -lIce -lIceUtil
```

See https://doc.zeroc.com/ice/3.6/ice-release-notes/using-the-linux-binary-distributions#id-.UsingtheLinuxBinaryDistributionsv3.6-C++